# What are environmentally friendly and efficient ways to fight hogweed?

Tags: pest-management, pesticides

There's a whole [movement](https://antiborschevik.info/) in Russia called "Antiborschevik" (Antihogweed). Sosnowsky's hogweed used to be cultivated on purpose in the Soviet Union as a type of fodder, but then it became an invasive nuisance spreading all over the place on its own. Among other things, they, the movement, suggest applying herbicides. But herbicides are bad, aren't they? What are both environmentally friendly and efficient ways to fight hogweed (Sosnowsky's hogweed)?

Answer (score 1):

Main problem is that the seeds can remain vital for 5 or more years, so any measurements taken need to be persisted for a while and there's really no silver bullet (also not herbicides since they're not guaranteed to kill seeds present in the soil). Repeatedly mowing/grazing makes sure existing plants cannot produce seeds. Grazing is efficient in that it doesn't require manual intervantion, but is not feasible in some areas because fencing does take manpower. And the flocks might eat other plants which can be undesired in case of rare species. Mowing could be less environmentally friendly (possible fuel use, soil compacting or degradation). Mowing followed by removing a large part of the root might be efficient enough that it needs to be done once, but again requires more manpower and disturbs soil (which in turn might lead to seeds getting more chances). All in all, as is often the case for other invasive species, it is just a hard problem.